# Convert octet-stream to zip file

Tags: linux, files, zip, archive

[image]I tried to zip a backup folder that contains 50 GB of data. The result is a octet-stream (full 50 GB) instead of a zip file.

I have already erased the source data before I realize the issue.

Is there a way to fix this? i.e. to create a zip file of these data? or to extract data from the octet-stream?

Comment: What command did you use to create the `zip` file?

Comment: What does `unzip -l backup.zip` say?

Comment: The `-I` option is invalid on my Linux. What is your distro, and what does the man page say it does? Mine has a `-i` option which "emits mime-strings rather than human-readable ones". I suspect your file *is* a .zip, but you suppressed that information. If the contents of your folder were already compressed (e.g. images) then zip will not achieve significant reductions, so 50GB would be understandable.

Comment: @StephenKitt i get the following : Archive:  backup.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  backup.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of backup.zip or
        backup.zip.zip, and cannot find backup.zip.ZIP, period.

Comment: @RomeoNinov on windows -> right click on the folder -> add to archive

Comment: @Paul_Pedant   -i                         do not further classify regular files
  -I, --mime                 output MIME type strings (--mime-type and
                               --mime-encoding).  I am using file-5.41. So it doesn't seem the end of the world according to you. How would you fix this?

Comment: A ZIP file has a directory structure as its end, and it should be able to extract its contents even if there is leading garbage before the ZIP compressed data. When the  directory structure cannot be found it probably means that either the creation was not successful, maybe terminated prematurely, or that the file was damaged afterwards, e.g. during a file transfer. If this is the case, the best fix would be to create the ZIP file again. BTW: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I see the reply to @RomeoNinov that this file was created in some version (which?) of Windows in the File Manager GUI. Is it possible to transfer the archive back to Windows and check the contents there?

How did the .zip get to be on a Linux system? Something like FTP needs to be configured to transfer in binary mode (as opposed to ascii mode) to avoid having bytes that look like newline converted, for example.

Linux `zip` only claims it works for .zip file created in MSDOS, OS/2, Windows 9x/NT/XP. No mention of Win 7, 10 or 11 there. You might try `7z` instead of `unzip`, as it may deal with more recent Windows formats.

I see you are working in `/tmp`. You might show the results of `df -h /tmp`. Any file transfer between machines may have failed due to lack of space, and 50GB seems generous for /tmp, so the file may indeed be incomplete, as the error message says. Also, /tmp tends to get cleared at reboot, so it would be easy to lose the backup.zip file itself.

It may prove impossible to recover this data, due to the chain of operations which it has undergone.

Comment: The file was created originally in windows 10 64 bit system. I transferred the file via my SD card to my MAC book and tried to extract it there. I tried 7-zip on both mac and windows and neither worked. Any suggestion on what else I can do?